# Spring warns about not having jackson-module-kotlin

Tags: okhttp

Just upgraded OkHttp to 4.4.0 and came from 3.3.0.
I understand OkHttp now relies on Kotlin, but this now gives some unwanted side-effects with Spring Boot (2.2.5) and Jackson as it now warns about not having the `com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin` on the classpath.

Now I'm kind of forced to add this lib, because moving to 4.4.0 to prevent this warning.
Is there a way to prevent this somehow? I guess not having kotlin on the classpath is not possible ;-)

Answer (score 3):

OkHttp transitively pulls the kotlin stdlib into your classpath.
This is detected by jackson which in turn emits the warning.

Unless you have some DTO classes written in Kotlin which should be (de-)serialized by jackson, you can ignore the warning.

Comment: Ist there a way to disable the warning?

Comment: exclude the transitive dependency? @RoToRa

Comment: @SimonH But does OkHttp then still work? Doesn't it need the Kotlin lib?

Comment: It will still use it internally, it just won't transitively import it to your project... I think